# I want to speed up the eval of Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I was allowed to run the [zxcvbn.js (Javascript library)](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) to Nashorn.
But there is one problem.

eval (pre-compile) is very slow. It takes about 3 minutes.
I want to move more quickly.

```
public class StrengthChecker {

  private static final String ZXCVBN_PATH = "/META-INF/resources/webjars/zxcvbn/1.0/zxcvbn.js";

  private final ScriptEngine engine;

  public StrengthChecker() {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

    Bindings engineScope = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    engineScope.put("window", engineScope);

    try {

      // -------------------------------------------
      // Here is very slow definition of zxcvbn.js.
      // -------------------------------------------
      engine.eval(getResourceContents(ZXCVBN_PATH));

    } catch (ScriptException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public Strength check(String pw) {
    try {
      Map<String, Object> result;
      result = (Map<String, Object>) engine.eval("zxcvbn('" + pw + "');");

      return new Strength(
        ((Double) result.get("entropy")).intValue(),
        (int) result.get("score"),
        ((Double) result.get("crack_time")).intValue()
      );
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Please tell us something solution.

Comment: So when you run the javascript code in a browser rather than in Nashorn, it isn't that slow?

Comment: When the browser is fast.And it is faster when running in Nashorn. But it is slow when you load a library (zxcvbn.js) in Nashorn.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known performance bug that has been fixed, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8137333. It should be released with Java 8u72, slated for January 2016. Pre-release builds of Java 9 available at https://jdk9.java.net/download/ also contain the fix (since JDK9 build b85).

Comment: Thank you for giving me good answer.
I appreciate your kindness.